# Replace rails param value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a search form that I would like to have the "last searched values" pre-pop the fields when the user submits a search (The search form and the results are on the same page). If there is no previous search, the fields have placeholder values.

**Search Field**

```
<%= text_field_tag(:search_zip, nil, placeholder: " Zip Code", class: "common_search_field search_zip", onkeypress: "return isNumber(event);", maxlength: "5", required: true, value: params[:search_zip]) %>
```

**Submit Button**

```
<%= submit_tag("Search", class: "search_submit_btn", onclick: "prePopSearchForm();") %>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  function prePopSearchForm(){
    "<%= params[:search_zip] %>" = $(".search_zip").val();
  }
```

The problem is the `params[:search_zip]` keeps the original `params[:search_zip]` value in the :search_zip form-field. I would like to take the current value when the submit button is clicked, and assign it as the `params[:search_zip]` value. I am new to Rails & JavaScript, so if this is not best practice I would appreciate a push in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: rails runs on the server and javascript runs in the browser. This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it isn't clear what you are expecting to do here.

Comment: You are correct. This will have the be done with AJAX. I am going to remove the `submit_tag` and replace it with a button that submits an AJAX form with all the form-field values. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score -1):

That should actually work in a different way. As all http it's request-response cycle, so to use new `search_zip` in controller you need to send request to web server. You can do it like this:

```
function prePopSearchForm(){
  window.location.search = 'search_zip=' + $(".search_zip").val();
}
```

But better way would be to actually submit form with all fields:

```
function prePopSearchForm(){
  $(".search_zip").closest('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: last one makes no sense ... event is already being triggered on a submit button

Comment: it's triggered if button is inside the form, as you are using `onclick` handler it may be not the case

Comment: no that's not true unless the default event is prevented and there is no point using a click handler to do what default will already do

Comment: same with first one...form would do that also if set method to GET